# encircle a table div Without changing the size of the cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I developped a diagram in a HTML table, the TD have fixed dimension and i want to highlight this div with something like border or circle but if i simply use the "border : ... "  of css it deformed the div.

I can't use the "background-color" because it is already use for an other information.

Comment: Can you share your markup and stylesheet with us? Learn how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please add code for better understanding...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ju4ynkf6/1/ this is an example who deformed my cell, is it possible to make something like border but outside the cell.

Comment: The jsfiddle is not good enough. What if the site is down or you remove it? Then your question is not helpful to future people. Edit your question and add your code into a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try using pseudo-elements such as `::before` or `::after` ?

Or `box-shadow` property to simulate inside borders ?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: it's something intersesting, i will look for other possibilities thank you.